# How to lessen emission of an enclosure box from I/O ports?

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, port

I am designing an enclosure box which will contain motor controllers(TB6600), microcontroller(ESP32 and Arduino Mega) and a 12 V power supply. I have not decided which material will enclose this. My previous design uses an empty computer case to enclose the controller.

How to design an enclosure which will prevent EMI leakages? A research I found mention that leakages mostly happen in the Input/ Output ports. What component should I buy to lessen the emission from the I/O port? See image below for reference (2,4).

[image]

edit: I focused my question now on the I/O port source of emission.

Comment: It all depends on the context of the enclosure. Is this a bare board, or a CPU in a box, with or without cables penetrating. More information is needed.

Comment: Minimizing emissions (both radiated and conducted) is to a large extent depending on your board and circuit design skills. Surely, you can build your project in a plastic enclosure and pass EMI testing. So I am afraid this can't be answered in general. To provide an educated guess, one would need at least schematics and board layout. Then again, don't expect a detailed project review for free from this site. Asking more specifically will get you some answers though. (I would vote to close this again as it still lacks substantial focus, but can't)

Answer (score 0):

Even when considering I/O only, it is a very dependent question.

In general:

- provide filters for I/O when going through the enclosure. Series impedance (R or bead) and if possible C to chassis. Just allow enough bandwidth to pass so your I/O still works. This prevents pesky 100 MHz common mode noise from getting into/out of the box.
- accompany every signal with a neighboring return conductor.
- for power in/out you can achieve good common-mode suppression with a common mode choke. With beads or resistors, this is rather hard on high current lines.
- Join cable shields immediately with chassis wall using appropriate connectors.

Even when you adhere to all of this, it will be still possible to screw up EMC by bad routing. Therefore, the above are merely general guidelines that generally *help* (never hurt) but may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

To see what connector types are possible, you need to specify the voltages, currents, and frequencies of the signals.  For example, fully shielded D-sub connectors are a standard item, but they will not work with RF signals.

If you have to use a connector with a plastic body, and option is to make a small metal box that is like an oversized backshell.  The box mounts around the connector to the inside of the connector panel.  This reduces the effective aperture from the area of the connector's plastic body to the area of a very small hole with the wires going through it to the back side of the connector.

Also, for the shielded enclosure, make sure all of the joints between two pieces of sheet metal are overlapping, not butt-joints.  Of course, die casting or welding are better.